# Gorm ORM in Go - Polymorphic associations - how to access the subtype idiomatically

Tags: go-gorm

I'm using Gorm ORM and have a polymorphic association set up between Items and the subtypes Weapon/Armor/Jewelry.

```
type Item struct {
    models.Model
    // see https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Polymorphism-Association
    SubID     string
    SubType   string
    CraftedBy string
}

type ItemWeaponSubtype struct {
    models.Model
    Items           []Item `gorm:"polymorphic:Sub;polymorphicValue:weapon"`
    Name            string
    Quality         string `gorm:"type:varchar(20)""`
    Material        string `gorm:"type:varchar(20)""`
    EquipmentSlotId string
    DamageBonuses
}
```

I want to be able to have a list of item names (e.g. for an inventory listing).  Ultimately I want to be able to get out any other common attributes that are shared between all the subtypes (like maybe a weight, cost, etc).

I'm not happy with the "solution" that I have and I think that there has to be a better way to do this.  Could anybody with more experience than me show me a pattern that accomplishes this?

My idea was to have a nested function that is able to build up the DTO that has the common attributes.

But I will need a switch statement for every item type that I want to support.

```
// ItemCommonDetails contains fields that all subtypes have and is useful for displaying inventory lists etc
type ItemCommonDetails struct {
    Name string
}

func (ir *ItemRepository) GetItemCommonDetailsFromId(itemId string) (ItemCommonDetails, error) {
    var item models.Item
    result := ir.db.First(&item, "id = ?", itemId)
    if 0 == result.RowsAffected {
        return ItemCommonDetails{Name: "Err!"}, &common_dto.StatusError{Code: http.StatusNotFound, Message: "Item [" + itemId + "] not found"}
    }

    defineReturn := func(result *gorm.DB, name string) (ItemCommonDetails, error) {
        if result.RowsAffected == 0 {
            return ItemCommonDetails{Name: "Err!"}, &common_dto.StatusError{Code: http.StatusNotFound, Message: "Item [" + itemId + "] not found"}
        }
        return ItemCommonDetails{Name: name}, nil
    }

    switch item.SubType {
    case "weapon":
        var weapon models.ItemWeaponSubtype
        result := ir.db.First(&weapon, "id = ?", item.SubID)
        return defineReturn(result, weapon.Name)
    case "armor":
        var armor models.ItemArmorSubtype
        result := ir.db.First(&armor, "id = ?", item.SubID)
        return defineReturn(result, armor.Name)
    case "jewelry":
        var jewelry models.ItemJewelrySubtype
        result := ir.db.First(&jewelry, "id = ?", item.SubID)
        return defineReturn(result, jewelry.Name)
    default:
        return ItemCommonDetails{Name: "Err!"}, &common_dto.StatusError{Code: http.StatusNotFound, Message: "Item [" + itemId + "] not found"}
    }
}
```

Is there a more general way to do this?  I can't find anything in the Gorm documentation that lets you magically pull the subtype from the Item.  I think this would be hard to type hint properly, but maybe some sort of reflection method exists that would let me pull out common attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty late response, but I would offer that perhaps you should take another look at your table relationship. From a database design perspective, if you have shared properties on multiple tables, then it may be worth extracting those properties out to another table and having each of the original tables reference that table. Simple example:

```golang
// originally, we have Car and Bike sharing the attributes NumWheels and Owner
type Car struct {
  NumWheels int
  Owner string
  Mileage int
  Make string
  Model string
}

type Bike struct {
  NumWheels int
  Owner string
  Color string
  Brand string
}

// one refactoring later...
type Vehicle struct {
  NumWheels int
  Owner string
}

type Car struct {
  Vehicle
  Mileage int
  Make string
  Model string
}

type Bike struct {
  Vehicle
  Color string
  Brand string
}
```

Okay, so that's a simple polymorphic example where car and bike are both *vehicles*, so we can just use go's struct embedding syntax. But if you consider items, perhaps they *always* have a weight, a cost, etc. You could simply move those attributes into your Item model instead of containing them in your sub types. Alternatively, you can define methods (not 100% of the language Go uses to describe this concept) on your structs so that you can utilize an interface:

```
type Itemlike interface {
  GetWeight() int
  GetCost() int
  // etc
}

func GetProperties(i *Itemlike) map[string]int {
  res := map[string]int{"weight": i.GetWeight(), "cost": i.GetCost()}
  return res
}
```

Obviously, this later example doesn't help with *querying*, only after querying are you able to use this `GetProperties` function. So you could query for the full list of everything in the inventory, then call the your `GetProperties` (or similar) function on each item in that list